# Symfony 3.4 functional testing. Authentication doesn't work

Tags: fosuserbundle, functional-testing

I'm using the code to log in the user und get the page /transactions. But it doesn't work for me. The status code is not 200, but 302. I'm using the FOSUser-Bundle. Has anybody an idea?

```
    $client = static::createClient();

    $client->request('GET', '/transactions', array(), array(), array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'user',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'password',
    )); 

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

After auth you are redirected - so  302 header is  ok .  It's not an  error .

Instead status code  you should  chceck response body , or url where you were redirected

Comment: no, it's wrong. The 302-redirect means, I would be redirected to the login page

Comment: but after successfull login you are also  redirected , that's  why i think  that test parameters  are  wrong, nad code is ok